# How to call seo tags from db

Tags: ruby-on-rails

in db column having hash format title mobile description

i need to call these fields in a view page tags. how ? iam new to ror
step by step will be more helpful.

Comment: any code share?

Comment: @Anand .. need to add tags on existing application.bro.

Comment: how does this`hash format` look? any example?

Comment: @Anand  {:keyword => "Talek", :mobile => "789966558"}

Comment: please have a look on answer and hope it helped it, you can modify it accordingly, feel free to upvote/accept the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

suppose your db column returns mobile_description so in controller you defined it ex-

```
@mobile_description = {:keyword => "Talek", :mobile => "789966558"}
```

and in view_page you can use these as tags where you want to show it like this ex -

mobile number `@mobile_description[:mobile]`

mobile title `@mobile_description[:keyword]`

Comment: in bd column hash fields will be dynamically updated.

i need to call those hash fields in meta tag syntax..

Comment: yes you can use that for example`<h3>Mobile:</h3> <span>@mobile_description[:mobile]</span>` and so on

Comment: <% # Meta information for the <head> section %> <% title @ post.title %> <% meta_tag :description, @ post.description %> <% meta_tag :keywords, @ post.keywords.join(',') %> <% # Actual view content %> <h2><%= @post.title %></h2> <div class='content'><%= @ post.body %></div>


in ruby meta tags will be like as i came to know by google.


can u modify this 
tags

for me 

for table name: flight

column : search

hash filelds:

mobile , keywords, description